# HTML 5 Geolocation in China

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, geolocation

I'm using the following code in an application in order to retrieve the users location.

```
function getGeoCoords() {
  var deferred = $.Deferred();
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(deferred.resolve, deferred.reject);
  return deferred.promise();
}
```

This is used by the following:

```
return deferred.pipe(function() {
 console.log('Getting user location. . .');
 return getGeoCoords();
}).pipe(function (position)) {
. . .
```

This code has been tested and works well in all browsers, except Chrome.

It seems that it is also constrained to China. Other browsers tested there (even IE) worked without a hitch. But for some reason, I am unable to use the Geolocation API to retrieve the location of a user in China on Chrome.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

take a look https://www.zhihu.com/question/20473051

in short, the reason is that the chrome  needs to send the location infomation to a google server, but the server may be blocked in china

Answer (score 0):

Six years later I still can't make this work in Chrome.
But there are working examples, so how do they do that?

Here's what my problem is in particular:

I'm in China and I need to make a website that displays a map with a "Get my location" button. To simplify, if I run the following code in debugger, in some environments it will not get my location. Can anyone tell me why?

`navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success => console.log(success), err => console.error(err))`

I can get the location in these environments:

- My Macbook uses 4G from my phone (hotspot), Safari browser.
- PC uses internet from LAN, Edge browser.

I CANNOT get the location in these environments:

- My Macbook uses internet from LAN, Safari browser.
- PC uses internet from LAN, Chrome version 68 as well as the Chinese QQ browser:
  Error: {
  code:2,
  message:"Network location provider at 'https://www.googleapis.com/' : No response received."
  }
- PC uses internet from LAN, Chome 103 or Firefox: No success and no error received.

In all cases, location services are enabled and VPN is not used.
I know, `googleapis.com` is not available in China. But Baidu, Gaode Amap, or QQ Map should work on Chrome and they don't.